# How do RSS readers read different feeds?

Tags: xml, parsing, rss

sorry for a silly question, (I know it is). I didn't work with RSS before and I have a question. I wrote an RSS reader for iphone which can read one particular feed, if I try to read some other feed it doesn't work properly, I have some data missing, or sometimes it even crashes. Ok, it is naturally enough, because different feeds have different date formats, different xml elements names etc.
So I don't understand how all this readers where you only need to provide url parse every feed

Thank you very much))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure your app is adhering to [RSS Standards](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification)

W3C has a [validation tool](http://validator.w3.org/feed/) to verify that the RSS you're consuming is good coming in.

Comment: You also have the Atom standard. Basically, there are just a handful of standards.